# Создание двумерного массива (треугольника) из строки Python

Tags: python, массивы, list, генераторы

Имеем строку

```
 triangle = """75
              95 64
              17 47 82
              18 35 87 10
              20 04 82 47 65
              19 01 23 75 03 34
              88 02 77 73 07 63 67
              99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
              41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
              41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
              53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
              70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
              91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
              63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
              04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"""
```

Необходимо получить на выходе двумерный массив в виде треугольника:

```
nums = [[75],
        [95, 64],
        [17, 47, 82]]
```

Я смог получить только список из данной строки, таким методом:

```
triangle_nums = [triangle[i:i+2] for i, _ in enumerate(triangle) if triangle[i:i+2].isdigit() 
                 and i + 2 <= len(triangle)]
```

Вывод print(triangle_nums):

```
['75', '95', '64', '17', '47', '82', '18', '35', '87', '10', '20', '04', '82', '47', '65', '19', '01', '23', '75', '03', '34', '88', '02', '77', '73', '07', '63', '67', '99', '65', '04', '28', '06', '16', '70', '92', '41', '41', '26', '56', '83', '40', '80', '70', '33', '41', '48', '72', '33', '47', '32', '37', '16', '94', '29', '53', '71', '44', '65', '25', '43', '91', '52', '97', '51', '14', '70', '11', '33', '28', '77', '73', '17', '78', '39', '68', '17', '57', '91', '71', '52', '38', '17', '14', '91', '43', '58', '50', '27', '29', '48', '63', '66', '04', '68', '89', '53', '67', '30', '73', '16', '69', '87', '40', '31', '04', '62', '98', '27', '23', '09', '70', '98', '73', '93', '38', '53', '60', '04', '23']
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь методом `split` два раза:

- с разделителем "конец строки"
- со стандартным пробельным разделителем

```py
triangle_nums = [list(map(int, x.split())) for x in triangle.split('\n')]
```

Результат:

```
[[75],
 [95, 64],
 [17, 47, 82],
 [18, 35, 87, 10],
 [20, 4, 82, 47, 65],
 [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
 [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
 [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
 [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
 [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
 [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
 [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
 [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
 [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
 [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Использование `map` и `lambda` позволяет весь код свернуть в одну строку.

```
nums = list(map(lambda x: list(map(int, x.split())), triangle.split('\n')))
```

Если по каким-то причинам однострочники из двух ответов вам не подойдут, то так это можно сделать "по нормальному":

```
nums = [x for x in triangle.split('\n')]
for i in range(len(nums)):
    nums[i] = nums[i].split()
    for j in range(len(nums[i])):
        nums[i][j] = int(nums[i][j])
```

Comment: Странное дело, но `split()` без параметров позволяет обходиться без `strip()`. А, всё в описании есть: "None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
  and discard empty strings from the result."

Comment: @CrazyElf благодарю за информацию. сейчас подправлю

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам, для разнообразия, решение через pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
res = pd.read_csv(StringIO(triangle), header=None)[0].str.split().apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x]).values.tolist()
```

res:

```
[75]
[95, 64]
[17, 47, 82]
[18, 35, 87, 10]
[20, 4, 82, 47, 65]
[19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34]
[88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67]
[99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92]
[41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33]
[41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29]
[53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14]
[70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57]
[91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48]
[63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31]
[4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23]
```

Comment: у  меня есть подозрение, что для реально больших мультистрок это решение может быть довольно эффективным.